# jquery featured ui scroller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jscrollpane

Im looking to modify the jquery featured ui example.  It displays 4 thumbs to the right and im wondering if i were to have more like 8 how could i get my scroller to move with the highlighted feature?.

I have an example here for everyone to review.  How can i get the div that contains the thumbs to move when the selected item is being displayed?

Sample Here:
http://www.barberveri.com/featured/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses [jQuery UI Tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#default) and [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#) plugin.

I think this behavior can be achieve by using the method `scrollToElement()` from the jScrollPane plugin and the `show` callback from jQuery UI Tabs.

Basically, when the next tab content is displayed automatically, get the instance of the jScrollPane plugin from jquery data (to get access to the API) and use `ui.tab` (current tab button) to scrollToElement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featured > #thumbs ul")
        .tabs({
            fx: { opacity: "toggle" },
            show: function(e, ui) {
                // when the next tab is displayed, scroll to this new element
                var plugin = $('.ui-tabs-nav').data('jsp');
                if (plugin) {
                    plugin.scrollToElement(ui.tab, false);
                }
            }
        })
        .tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

---

**Edit:** How to stop rotation when hovering a panel.

According to the [jquery tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-rotate), the rotation can be stopped when passing a null value for the `ms` parameter (second)

> Set up an automatic rotation through tabs of a tab pane. The second
>   argument is an amount of time in milliseconds until the next tab in
>   the cycle gets activated. Use 0 or null to stop the rotation. The
>   third controls whether or not to continue the rotation after a tab has
>   been selected by a user. Default: false.

Use the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method to call the rotate method when hovering the panels:

```
$('.ui-tabs-panel').hover(
    // stops the rotation when mouse enters
    function() { $tabs.tabs("rotate", null); },
    // restart it when mouse goes out
    function() { $tabs.tabs("rotate", 2000, true); }
);
```

---

Here is working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/MRcNC/).

Comment: Thanks Didier, in the fiddle example when it first loads there is a long gray box under the main image?

Comment: Disregard the above thing about the gray box under the main image in the fiddle example i resolved that.

Comment: One more dumb q.  how to pause this on hover of the large area

Comment: I noticed the gray box. I just copied your code to have a working example representing your situation so I did not focused on this. See my updated answer for the rotation.